# Name for javascript vertical execution

Tags: javascript, function

I was wondering the name of this type of coding, when you call others functions vertically. ie:

```
fs.readFileSync('data.txt', 'utf8')
  .trim()
  .split('\n')
  .map(line => line.split('\t'))
  .reduce((acum, elem) => {
    acum + parseInt(elem[1])
  }, 0)
```

Comment: It's called _chained calls_.

Comment: What do you mean "vertically"? These are chained function calls, just written in a way that they are aligned vertically (you could also write them in one line or aligned in any other way, though this way is arguably the most readable option)

Comment: This isn't necessarily "chained methods" because there are several intermediate values being used here. "Chained calls" seems the post appropriate. Some also call it a "pipeline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **method chaining.** It's a pretty neat way to structure a program.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) or *function chaining*. There is a [jQuery example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#jQuery) on Wikipedia.

Comment: From that article: "A method chain is also known as a _train wreck_" :D I think that's also an awesome descriptor (weirdly, seems to be more valid in other languages). I don't know if it's going to be edited from the page, so I wanted it to live somewhere.

Comment: @vlaz Nice observation! However, most people avoid that by putting line breaks between the method calls.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have to be called vertically, as the whitespace isn't the important part. What you're referring to is a "**Fluent Interface**" or just called "**chaining**", where every method returns the object so you can call another method.

Comment: "Fluent Interface" is not really a thing I've seen used to describe JavaScript but usually other OO languages. I think the reason is that a lot of the functions return "chainable" output, so it's not really exceptional, whereas fluent interface is supposed to mark the return as noteworthy.

Comment: @vlaz JavaScript is listed on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript).

Comment: @4castle then this is the first time I've seen it used to describe JavaScript. Probably also worth pointing out that FI generally means that the _same_ object is returned, so each next call in the chain operates on the underlying instance, while most of the time in JS each call just returns the _same type_ of data, e.g., `[1, 2, 3].map().filter()` will actually produce three arrays, not manipulate the same one. Also probably why FI doesn't crop up as much.